# Create a ASP.NET webservice with a JSON communication to iPhone

Tags: c#, asp.net, ios, json, web-services

we have a server and i need a ASP.NET webservice to access to an MS SQL 2008 database from my iPhone. I think that the best way is to create a Webservice in Csharp and communicate to an iPhone with JSON.

I couldn't find any tutorial how to create a simple web service with JSON.

Could you give me a little example like "hello world" so that i can see how its done? 
that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ServiceStack for this. A hello world tutorial can be found here:

http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/

The JSON example can be found here:

http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/servicestack/json/syncreply/Hello

Comment: No problem, this webservice is very easy to setup! You can also use WCF, but i found this more complicated and not easy to use.